# Finding the CDF when the PDF is given and the median

Tags: probability-distributions, median

Let $X$ be the annual income to a randomly selected person in a population group. It is normal to assume that $X$ is *Partero-distributed*, that means that $X$ has the PDF of

$$
f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\theta k^\theta x^{-\theta -1}& \text{for} ~~x>k\\0 & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}
$$

show that the CDF is given by

$$
F_X(x)=\begin{cases}1-k^\theta x^{-\theta} & \text{for} ~~x>k\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}  
$$

and find the median of the annual income

Me:

I know that

$$
\int^x_{-\infty}{f_X(x)dx}=F_X(x)
$$

since $x$ is not defined under $k$ we get $\int_k^x{f(x)}dx$ if we integrate this with respect to $x$ and apply the limits we would get

$$
F_X(x)=1-k^{\theta}x^{\theta} ~~\text{for}~~~ x>k
$$

now that that's done. I have to find the median. and this is where i'm stuck. Do I find the median of the CDF or PDF?

$$
F_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\Longrightarrow \int^M_? 1-k^{\theta}x^{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

and what under limit am i supposed to use?

Comment: Why are you integrating the CDF? Does not make sense. You have to find the value which makes $F(x)=1/2$

Comment: So, am i supposed to set $\int^M_k f_X(x)=.5$?

Comment: Yes, and the integral is your CDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is

$$
\int_{-\infty}^m f_X(x){\rm d}x = \frac{1}{2} = F(m)
$$

So the problem becomes

$$
\frac{1}{2} = 1 - \left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^{\theta}
$$

and from there

$$
\frac{k}{m} = 2^{-1/\theta}
$$

So the median is

$$
m = 2^{1/\theta}k
$$